# Why does using a fundamental type as a base-class compile sometimes?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

This compiles (tested with GCC 9 and Clang 9):

```
template<typename U>
struct inherit : U { };

int test(inherit<int> arg);
```

But this does not:

```
int test(inherit<int> arg) { }
```

Why does the first one compile?

Comment: Please also share the compile errors that you receive for the second snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int test(inherit<int> arg);` is just a declaration.  As such, we don't need to know about `inherit<int>` yet.  Because of that, the compiler will let it go.

With `int test(inherit<int> arg) { }` you now have a definition and now we need to know about `inherit<int>` so `arg` can be destroyed when the function exits.  At that point the template is instantiated and you get an error because it is invalid.

Another reason to ignore the declaration is that `inherit` could later on get specialized for `int` and that specialization might actually be a valid class since you could have something like

```
template<>
struct inherit<int> { };
```

If you were to add that between `int test(inherit<int> arg);` and `int test(inherit<int> arg) { }` then the code would now compile since `inherit<int>` is now a valid type.

Comment: Relevant quote: "The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete (possibly cv-qualified) class type in the context of the function definition unless the function is deleted".

Comment: Ah, very interesting. So for SFINAE, you actually have to access something inside the struct (i.e. put a `using type = int;` inside `inherit` and do `int test(inherit<int>::type arg);`) for the compiler to instantiate the template?

Comment: @Nerp That is SFINAE, but in order for it to know what `inherit<int>::type` it has to instantiate `inherit<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone else will explain the why. I will use a phenomenological approach here ;).

Your first version also fails to compile once you actually instantiate a `inherit<int>`:

```
int main() {
    test( inherit<int>{} );
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'struct inherit<int>':
prog.cc:9:24:   required from here
prog.cc:4:8: error: base type 'int' fails to be a struct or class type
    4 | struct inherit : U { };
      |        ^~~~~~~
```

I could have simply tried to create a `inherit<int>` object (without calling `test`) to get similar error.

On the other hand, this is just a declaration: `int test(inherit<int> arg);` so before actually providing the definition there could be a specialization for `inherit` that enables us to also provide a valid definition for `test`:

```
template<typename U>
struct inherit : U { };

// looks broken
int test(inherit<int> arg);
// but that this point we dont really know yet what `inherit<int>` really is

// whoops inherit<int> is something different now   
template <> struct inherit<int> {};

// ... and now this is completely fine
int test(inherit<int> arg) {}

int main() {
    test( inherit<int>{} );
}
```